# Storing a byte array into MySQL binary column with JdbcTemplate

Tags: mysql, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a MySQL table (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE `tokens` (
    `token` BINARY(16) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I try to insert a row like this:

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; // org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
...
String sql = "INSERT INTO `tokens` (`token`) VALUES (?)";
String token = "123e4567e89b12d3a456426655440000"; // UUID
jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[]{token.getBytes()});
```

But I get this exception:

```
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'token' at row 1
```

What do I do wrong? Thanks.

Edit: see my answer, I missed the hexadecimal conversion (token is an UUID).

Comment: "Data truncation: Data too long for column 'token' at row 1 "

Comment: increase size of column **token** . change `token BINARY(16)` to `token BINARY(32)`

Comment: @Arunkumar I was missing the hexadecimal conversion, a 32 chars UUID contains 16 hexadecimal codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to store the token (which is an UUID):

```
jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[]{DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(token)});
```

Let us know if there are other ways...